# Rustlings Errors3.rs Convert From String Error - Trait Not Implemented for `std::string::String`

Tags: rust, traits

I am working on the Rustlings course [Errors3.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/master/exercises/error_handling/errors3.rs):

```rust
// This is a program that is trying to use a completed version of the
// `total_cost` function from the previous exercise. It's not working though!
// Why not? What should we do to fix it?

use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn main() {
    let mut tokens = 100;
    let pretend_user_input = "8";

    let cost = total_cost(pretend_user_input)?;

    if cost > tokens {
        println!("You can't afford that many!");
    } else {
        tokens -= cost;
        println!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens);
    }
}

pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let processing_fee = 1;
    let cost_per_item = 5;
    let qty = item_quantity.parse::<i32>()?;

    Ok(qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee)
}
```

Here is my current code:

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn main() -> Result<String, String>  {
    let mut tokens = 100;
    let pretend_user_input = "8";

    let cost = total_cost(pretend_user_input)?;

    if cost > tokens {
        //println!("You can't afford that many!");
        Ok(format!("You can't afford that many!"))
    } else {
        tokens -= cost;
        //println!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens);
        Err(format!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens).to_string())
    }

}

pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let processing_fee = 1;
    let cost_per_item = 5;
    let qty = item_quantity.parse::<i32>()?;

    Ok(qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee)
}
```

I am at a loss as to how to correct the first error:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `std::string::String`
 --> src/main.rs:7:46
  |
7 |     let cost = total_cost(pretend_user_input)?;
  |                                              ^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::num::ParseIntError>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
  |
  = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <std::string::String as std::convert::From<&std::string::String>>
            <std::string::String as std::convert::From<&str>>
            <std::string::String as std::convert::From<std::borrow::Cow<'a, str>>>
            <std::string::String as std::convert::From<std::boxed::Box<str>>>
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`

error[E0277]: `main` has invalid return type `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::string::String>`
 --> src/main.rs:3:14
  |
3 | fn main() -> Result<String, String>  {
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `main` can only return types that implement `std::process::Termination`
  |
  = help: consider using `()`, or a `Result`
```

Based on the suggestions, regarding `From`, I tried changing `Ok(format!("You can't afford that many!"))` to `Ok(String::from("You can't afford that many!"))`. But it results in virtually the same error message.

I have tried looking at the Rust documentation for [std::convert::From](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html). This gave me the idea of trying:

```rust
let slug: &'static str = "You can't afford that many!";
if cost > tokens {
    //println!("You can't afford that many!");
    Ok(std::convert::From(slug))
} else {
    tokens -= cost;
    //println!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens);
    Err(format!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens).to_string())
}
```

Which results in the error:

```
error[E0423]: expected function, tuple struct or tuple variant, found trait `std::convert::From`
  --> src/main.rs:12:12
   |
12 |         Ok(std::convert::From(slug))
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not a function, tuple struct or tuple variant
```

Comment: If you click on the first link, you can see the instructions/rules as comments towards the top of the file. They are not that helpful. What is helpful is executing the command for the "hint", which yields : ```If other functions can return a `Result`, why shouldn't `main`?```

Comment: I didn't answer why you get their error because I think there is no point to explain it. The TL;DR is that `ParseIntError` can't be convert to a `String` because `String` doesn't not implement `From<ParseIntError>` because ... not one need this feature. Your conversion could work if it was implement by std.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tried to change the behaviour of the original program, the program must print something not return a String from the main (actually you can't return a String from the main, you must return something that implement [`Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html)).

The solution is close to what you did, `main()` must also return an error, there is two way, use real type or use dynamic trait. Your case is very simple so real type is the most simple:

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn main() -> Result<(), ParseIntError> {
    let mut tokens = 100;
    let pretend_user_input = "8";

    let cost = total_cost(pretend_user_input)?;

    if cost > tokens {
        println!("You can't afford that many!");
    } else {
        tokens -= cost;
        println!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens);
    }

    // we just return ok with nothing in it, this mean program terminated without error
    Ok(())
}

pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let processing_fee = 1;
    let cost_per_item = 5;
    let qty = item_quantity.parse::<i32>()?;

    Ok(qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee)
}
```

But you could also use a dynamic trait, it's more advance but not particular better:

```rust
use std::num::ParseIntError;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut tokens = 100;
    let pretend_user_input = "8";

    let cost = total_cost(pretend_user_input)?;

    if cost > tokens {
        println!("You can't afford that many!");
    } else {
        tokens -= cost;
        println!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens);
    }

    Ok(())
}

pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let processing_fee = 1;
    let cost_per_item = 5;
    let qty = item_quantity.parse::<i32>()?;

    Ok(qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee)
}
```

There is a lot of way to handle error in Rust. You can learn a lot on [this blog post](https://blog.yoshuawuyts.com/error-handling-survey/).

Comment: Based on the pattern from the previous couple of exercises in the course, I believe they want you to handle an "error case for each function". for ```total_cost``` the ```ParseIntError``` return should be triggered in the case that something other than an ```i32``` type is entered. I am less sure about main, but I believe they want the ```OK || Err``` returns to be triggered from inside the ```if/else``` statement.

Comment: After looking at the problem again, in the context of the previous exercises. I now believe you are correct. My concern was, that I could not figure out the purpose of this exercise in the series. I now realize that what is unique about this problem is that the ```?``` syntax in main "inherits" its error handling from the ```total_cost``` function.

Answer (score 1):

The hints say to use a different method which avoids the "?" operator.
This is my solution.

```
// errors3.rs
// This is a program that is trying to use a completed version of the
// `total_cost` function from the previous exercise. It's not working though!
// Why not? What should we do to fix it?
// Execute `rustlings hint errors3` for hints!


// I AM NOT DONE

use std::num::ParseIntError;

fn main() -> Result<(),ParseIntError>{
    let mut tokens = 100;
    let pretend_user_input = "8";
    let cost = total_cost(pretend_user_input);
    match cost {
        Ok(x) if x > tokens => 
            println!("You can't afford that many!"),
        Ok(x) => { 
            tokens -= x;
            println!("You now have {} tokens.", tokens);
        },
        Err(e) => (), 
    }
    Ok(())
}

pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let processing_fee = 1;
    let cost_per_item = 5;
    let qty = item_quantity.parse::<i32>()?;

    Ok(qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee)    
}
```

Comment: I was just looking at this problem.  I took the hint: `rustlings hint errors3` which is: "_`If other functions can return a `Result`, why shouldn't `main`?`_", to mean that main ***should*** return OK or Err -- Which this answer does.  These days, I gather that a better way is to have a `Termination< i32, ParseIntError>` to handle the `Ok(())` and propogate the 'try' `?` thing.